# the proof about the continuity of functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a function deﬁned on $[a, b]$ for some real numbers $a<b$ and assume $f(a) \le f(b)$. I have proved that the following if-then statement is true: If $f$ is continuous on [a, b], then for all real numbers $y$ such that $f(a) \le y \le f(b)$ there is a real number c such that $a\le c \le b$ and $f(c) = y$.

But now I'm confused about the converse of this if-then statement.Whether the converse statement is true or not?

Comment: Do you know how to write the converse?

Comment: I do not know it actually.

Comment: Take $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow [-1,1]$ as $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ for $x > 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The converse of the statement is:

"If for all real numbers $y$ such that $f(a)\leq y\leq f(b)$ there is a real number $c$ such that $a\leq c\leq b$ and $f(c)=y$, then $f$ is continuous."

The converse is false, and to see this, can you think of a function that attains all values between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, but isn't continuous?  Perhaps a line between $(a,f(a))$ and $\left(\frac{a+b}{2},f(b)\right)$ and then has a jump discontinuity?

Comment: so you mean the function should be discontinuous?

Comment: To disprove the statement, you need something that satisfies the hypothesis of the converse, but not the conclusion of the converse.  Since the conclusion of the converse is that the function is continuous, yes, you need a discontinuous function.

Comment: Ok!Thanks for your help

Comment: Surely this example doesn't work, if you put a jump discontinuity on a line then that value is no longer obtained for any $c$.

Comment: @JonathanHebert Not if the jump discontinuity occurs at a $c$ where $f(c)$ is not between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.  Observe that $a$ and $b$ are fixed in the problem.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean now; you're thinking something like this: http://i.imgur.com/ze34fIX.jpg; this has the required property on $[a,b]$, but is not continuous on $[a,b]$. Recognizing your function as non-Darboux is what raised my initial concerns, but our requirement is weaker, because Darboux requires this property for any defined interval.

Comment: @JonathanHebert That's exactly what I mean.